# How to properly us Task Queue from Postgres Triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers, rabbitmq, celery

My current architecture has multiple web application with a single point of storage - my postgres database. Now, I wanted to implement some tasks whenever certain things happen within the database, such as send email when new user create, notify admin if certain value has been changed, etc.

So the naive approach was to create tons and tons of triggers that would be specific for every action. Now, I didn't think that's a good idea because of all the maintaining and load on the database.

I also do not think having one trigger that does a LISTEN/NOTIFY to a node server is also a good idea because as things scale, this solution becomes cumbersome to deal with.

the potential solution would be to have a task queue like celery and rabbitMQ or another solution and somehow initiate tasks from the database triggers. It scales and can be relatively easy to manage in the future

My question would be: what is the appropriate method of integrating postgresql triggers with a task queue like celery (im open to other suggestions). I just do not know if the way I'm thinking about it is appropriate.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to have a separate process that can receive either an inter-process or HTTP notification indicating when there may be data in the database that needs processing.

It would process everything that's scheduled upon the process start, and then listen for incoming notifications when there may be some data.

In addition, you may add an occasional poll, like once every minute.

You should stay away from triggers, they require one extra connection that itself needs to be monitored in case it breaks, which in turn complicates the solution quite a bit.